# Getting error when trying to create vertices in cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I'm getting the error

> Cannot Initialize a variable of type 'LineVertex*' (aka '_Line Vertex*) with an rvalue of type 'void*'

This is the line of code:

```
  LineVertex *vertices = calloc(sizeof(LineVertex*), numberOfVertices);
```

This worked until I switched my class from .m to .mm and now it's throwing me that error and I don't know how to fix it. I am using Xcode 5 and the latest version of Cocos2D.  I read that it might have something to do with casting but I honestly don't know how to do that, I couldn't get it to work correctly.  Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this.

```
LineVertex *vertices = static_cast<LineVertex *>(calloc(sizeof(LineVertex*), numberOfVertices));
```

For further information, please take a look at the FAQ.

- [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ: Why must I use a cast to convert from void*?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-ptr)